# Can we travel with a faulty Malaysian visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, malaysia-airlines

We are suppose to travel from Kolkata, India to Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia.
The required procedures had been taken care of and the passports with the Malaysian visa has also arrived. 
But there is a slight problem in the visa printing.

In the visas for my two daughters, all the information is correct except for their photos.
The photos have been swapped.

Will this cause any problems with passport control / immigration?

Comment: Short answer, yes it will. The photo in the passport will be different than the visa in the passport, that's a big No No. You better send the passports again to the embassy/consulate and have them fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this may (will) cause problems. Most immigration officers match passport photos, visa photos with the person in front of them. Even though this is not your mistake, you can suffer because of this. My advice is to send the passports back and get this corrected. If you have a consulate in your city, contact them.
(Many times, immigration officer at the Kuala Lumpur airport is likely to understand your situation and can let you go but I would not advice you to travel with assumption that luck will play in your favor.)
Have a nice trip.